# Errors and warning on sui installation. Could not complete aws-sdk-ec2 (lib)

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, sui

can anybody help me to understand the next errors and why I can't install Sui on Linux WSL edition?

I use the following command:

`cargo install --locked --git https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui.git --branch devnet sui`

And I got the following errors:

```
   Compiling rusticata-macros v4.1.0
   Compiling ark-ec v0.4.1
warning: variable does not need to be mutable
   --> external-crates/move/move-prover/bytecode/src/verification_analysis.rs:374:13
    |
374 |         let mut info = data
    |             ----^^^^
    |             |
    |             help: remove this `mut`
    |
    = note: `#[warn(unused_mut)]` on by default

   Compiling serde_derive_internals v0.26.0
warning: variable does not need to be mutable
   --> external-crates/move/move-prover/bytecode/src/verification_analysis_v2.rs:741:13
    |
741 |         let mut info = targets
    |             ----^^^^
    |             |
    |             help: remove this `mut`

   Compiling ff v0.13.0
```

```
   Compiling diff v0.1.13
   Compiling hex-literal v0.4.1
warning: private item shadows public glob re-export
  --> external-crates/move/tools/move-cli/src/sandbox/utils/mod.rs:5:5
   |
5  | use crate::sandbox::utils::on_disk_state_view::OnDiskStateView;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: the name `OnDiskStateView` in the type namespace is supposed to be publicly re-exported here
  --> external-crates/move/tools/move-cli/src/sandbox/utils/mod.rs:45:9
   |
45 | pub use on_disk_state_view::*;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: but the private item here shadows it
  --> external-crates/move/tools/move-cli/src/sandbox/utils/mod.rs:5:5
   |
5  | use crate::sandbox::utils::on_disk_state_view::OnDiskStateView;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: `#[warn(hidden_glob_reexports)]` on by default

   Compiling encode_unicode v1.0.0
   Compiling anes v0.1.6
```

```
  Compiling jemalloc-ctl v0.5.0
   Compiling secp256k1 v0.27.0
warning: `move-stackless-bytecode` (lib) generated 2 warnings (2 duplicates)
error: could not compile `aws-sdk-ec2` (lib)

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/ed-diegofelix/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc --crate-name aws_sdk_ec2 --edition=2021 /home/ed-diegofelix/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/aws-sdk-ec2-0.29.0/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --diagnostic-width=108 --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debug-assertions=off --cfg 'feature="default"' --cfg 'feature="rt-tokio"' --cfg 'feature="rustls"' -C metadata=089dbd1b8b69da53 -C extra-filename=-089dbd1b8b69da53 --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install4iCXsH/release/deps -C strip=debuginfo -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install4iCXsH/release/deps --extern aws_credential_types=/tmp/cargo-install4iCXsH/release/deps/libaws_credential_types-43be701c521b6d61.rmeta --extern aws_http=/tmp/cargo-install4iCXsH/release/deps/libaws_http-00a4f077875a9b06.rmeta --extern aws_runtime=/tmp/cargo-install4iCXsH/release/deps/libaws_runtime-e114e97928c05b4c.rmeta --extern aws_smithy_async=/tmp/cargo-install4iCXsH/release/deps/libaws_smithy_async-f3e69175786dd72a.rmeta --extern aws_smithy_client=/tmp/cargo-install4iCXsH/release/deps/libaws_smithy_client-6afa975ee178dccc.rmeta --extern aws_smithy_http=/tmp/cargo-install4iCXsH/release/deps/libaws_smithy_http-4591e48b39931bb6.rmeta --extern aws_smithy_json=/tmp/cargo-install4iCXsH/release/deps/libaws_smithy_json-678f5536f8689f98.rmeta --extern aws_smithy_query=/tmp/cargo-install4iCXsH/release/deps/libaws_smithy_query-cdc56943e0eba00e.rmeta --extern aws_smithy_runtime=/tmp/cargo-install4iCXsH/release/deps/libaws_smithy_runtime-e22ff76de4f0667c.rmeta --extern aws_smithy_runtime_api=/tmp/cargo-install4iCXsH/release/deps/libaws_smithy_runtime_api-207fedf9235cb7f7.rmeta --extern aws_smithy_types=/tmp/cargo-install4iCXsH/release/deps/libaws_smithy_types-90ed9c59b09e0bf3.rmeta --extern aws_smithy_xml=/tmp/cargo-install4iCXsH/release/deps/libaws_smithy_xml-52f26da352c9d836.rmeta --extern aws_types=/tmp/cargo-install4iCXsH/release/deps/libaws_types-64df58427c53d7fb.rmeta --extern fastrand=/tmp/cargo-install4iCXsH/release/deps/libfastrand-f2d30a22006a81d5.rmeta --extern http=/tmp/cargo-install4iCXsH/release/deps/libhttp-d07dd6dbfb3b0725.rmeta --extern regex=/tmp/cargo-install4iCXsH/release/deps/libregex-0c67f262fe8699c5.rmeta --extern tokio_stream=/tmp/cargo-install4iCXsH/release/deps/libtokio_stream-1c5c5f640db0d197.rmeta --extern tracing=/tmp/cargo-install4iCXsH/release/deps/libtracing-e523f226b1b82bc0.rmeta --cap-lints allow -L native=/tmp/cargo-install4iCXsH/release/build/ring-b2125e3dc5e34eea/out` (signal: 9, SIGKILL: kill)
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
warning: `move-cli` (lib) generated 1 warning (1 duplicate)
error: failed to compile `sui v1.12.0 (https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui.git?branch=devnet#1b5f809a)`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/tmp/cargo-install4iCXsH`.
To reuse those artifacts with a future compilation, set the environment variable `CARGO_TARGET_DIR` to that path.
```

I tried this

`rustup update stable`
`source "$HOME/.cargo/env"`

But it got me the same error.

I installed npm as well thinking about something is wrong but I still have the same errors.

It's suppose I'd get something like this

[Expected output](https://1ba6ce27946d04daf60a668665de63d2.cdn.bubble.io/f1696236848727x280356073678702300/q2_s5_eo.png

)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have figured this out already, if not it's very likely you don't have enough memory for you wsl instance, you can find or create wslconfig to increase the memory or close all other process that might be taking too much memory.

you can also try suibase, https://github.com/chainmovers/suibase, it will help you avoid the building step as they have compiled binaries ready for use.